# How do I relate the data from my entities? ASP.NET MVC 5 EF 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC application and I'm not quite sure how to make some relations between my entities.

I have the following entities

```
namespace Entities
{
    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }

    public class Classroom
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Capacity { get; set; }
    }

    public class CoffeeSpace
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Capacity { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My problem is this: a training event is going to happen in a school. The people will be distributed in classrooms with variable capacity and the training will happen in two steps. There will also happen two coffee breaks with two distinct areas.

The application should allow to:

- Register people with name and surname;
- Register classrooms with name and capacity;
- Register coffee areas with name and capacity.

The difference in the number of people in each classroom should be of at maximum 1 person. To stimulate the knowledge exchange, half the people in each classroom should move to another classroom between each step of the training.

When consulting a person registered in this event, the application should return the classroom this person will stay in each step of the training and the area where they will do each coffee break.

When consulting a classroom or coffee area registered in this event, the application should return a list of people that will be in that classroom/area in each step/break of the event.

I'm new to programming in general, and I know there are some kind of relations you can do between your entities using entity framework, but looking at it I'm completely lost and I can't seem to understand what type of relation I should use in this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would resolve this problem with middle tables 'between' Person and Classroom, would name it PersonxClass:

```
public class PersonxClass 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public int ClassId { get; set; }
}
```

in this entity I will save persons that are in a specific Classroom. good, second step, I will do another entity 'between' Person and CoffeeSpace, would name it PersonxCoffee:

```
public class PersonxCoffee 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public int CoffeeId { get; set; }
}
```

Equals that the before case, in this entity i will save data of persons for each CoffeeSpace.
I wait that this info is help for you.